# What is an integrated modelling tool?

Tags: numerical-modelling, modeling, model

In [this document](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/JINTRAC%3A-A-System-of-Codes-for-Integrated-of-Romanelli-Corrigan/f916c40aa342fb86a95db242a449aa3e8d4618d0) they describe their code as an integrated modelling tool. I am trying to understand how this is different from a regular modelling tool? Most codes include different modules that do different tasks, but I have never heard anyone refer to this as an integrated code. What does a code have to do to become an integrated code as opposed to a regular code?

Comment: In the fusion plasma physics community it is common to use the words "integrated modeling" for frameworks performing self-consistent coupled simulations of many different aspects of the whole multi-physics system. That can include MHD stability, and RF heating, and runaway electrons, and material wall heating, and dozens of other things - all running together to provide an integrated model for time evolution (or steady-state) scenario.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have a much better understanding of what they mean by integrated modelling now.